# update User information mongoose, MongoDB, NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on an edit-profile page and i want to change/update the information of the documents in my mongooseDB, but my code does not update the document. Any suggestions?

```
router.get('/edit', isAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('profile/editprofile', {
        user: req.user
    });
});
router.post('/edit', isAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {

    User.update({_id: req.session.passport.user.id}, {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        name: req.body.name,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        classc: req.body.classc,
        //graduated: req.body.graduated;
        major: req.body.major,
        minor: req.body.mino,
        linkedin: req.body.linkedin,
        bio: req.body.bio
    }, function (err){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.render('profile/profile', {
        user: req.user
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten to add `$set` operator

```
router.post('/edit', isAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {

    console.log(req.user._id) //console like this

    User.update({_id: req.user._id}, {$set: req.body}, function (err){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.render('profile/profile', {
        user: req.user
    });
});
});
```

Comment: if we already have an instance of user model which we want to update then there is any method to update the user directly and after the update we get the updated document?